# Fieldset labels showing on vfpage but respective data not showing on vfpage

Tags: visualforce, fieldsets, data-import-wizard

I have create two fieldset and working as wizard format first page showing first fieldset and second page showing second fieldset (using next,previoud commandbutton) . Fieldset label are showing but its respective data not showing on VFpage.

this is my class
public with sharing class wizardFieldsetController {
    public list account{get; set;}
    public list account2{get; set;}
    public String fields ='';

```
public list<Account> geta() {
    if(account == null) account = new list<Account>();
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.AccountFieldSet.getFields()) {
        fields += f.getFieldPath() + ',';
    }

    fields = fields.removeEnd(',');
    String queryString = 'SELECT '+fields+' FROM Account';
    account = Database.query(queryString);
    return account;

}

public list<Account> getb() {
    if(account2 == null) account2 = new list<Account>();
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.AccountFieldSet2.getFields()) {
        fields += f.getFieldPath() + ',';
    }

    fields = fields.removeEnd(',');
    String queryString = 'SELECT '+fields+' FROM Account';
    account2 = Database.query(queryString);
    return account2;

}
public pageReference next() {
    return page.wizardFieldset2;
}
public pageReference previous() {
    return page.wizardFieldset;
}

public PageReference save() {
    upsert account;

    upsert account2;
    return null;

}
```

}

this is my first vfpage

```
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockButtons>
 <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!next}" />
 </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

this is my second vfPage

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account2}" var="templist" rules="rows">
  <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets.AccountFieldset2}" var="f">
    <apex:column headervalue="{!f.label}">
       <apex:inputField value="{!templist[f.fieldPath]}"> </apex:inputField>
    </apex:column>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockTable>

<apex:pageBlockButtons>
 <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!previous}" />
      <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
 </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you using same controller for all pages, Please use the PageRefrence redirect metehod to maintain state of controller.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm

Thanks,